# Object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'attr'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to prepend every menu item with URL present in the browser( have to do it because of some url redirecting stuff). But its giving error in the line mentined below. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way?

```
          $(window).load(function () {
            var Home = window.location.pathname;
            alert(Home);
            path = $("#menu ul li a");

            $.each(path, function (key, value) {
                console.log(value);
                alert(value);
```

> ```
>             //These line give error: 
>             //Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'attr'
> ```

```
                var link =  value.attr("href");
                value.attr("href", Home + link );
            });


        });
```

HTML

```
 <div class="menu" id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li><div class="menuline"></div>
        <li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li><div class="menuline"></div>
        <li><a href="Albums">Photos</a></li><div class="menuline"></div>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li><div class="menuline"></div>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - You can remove that code altogether.

Each element inside a jQuery object is actually a DOM element, so when you traverse it using `$.each()` you will be working with the actual DOM element and not the nicely wrapped goodness of jQuery. Instead of `$.each()` you could use `$.fn.each()`:

```
$("#menu ul li a").each(function() {
    // this references the DOM element and we change its 'href' attribute.
    this.setAttribute('href', Home + this.getAttribute('href');
});
```

That said, when you have `<a href="bla.html">...</a>`, internally the `href` property already starts with `window.location.pathname` because your links are taken relative to the current document.

#### Update

You can also use the [`.attr(name, fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) method like so:

```
$('menu ul li a').attr('href', function(_, value) {
    return Home + value;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `jQuery` object instead of `Dom` to call `attr()` as `each()` gives you DOM object not the jQuery object

```
$(value).attr("href", Home + link );
```

You can also use DOM object to directly assign value to href

```
value.href = Home + link;
```

> The .each() is used directly on a jQuery collection. It iterates over
>   each matched element in the collection and performs a callback on that
>   object. The index of the current element within the collection is
>   passed as an argument to the callback. The value (the DOM element in
>   this case) is also passed, but the callback is fired within the
>   context of the current matched element so the this keyword points to
>   the current element as expected in other jQuery callbacks, [jQuery
>   docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: This is correct. It's important to note that jQuery objects are wrappers around sets of elements under most circumstances. That means you can treat them as arrays. `someOb[3]` = third object in set. Such, `.each()` will loop through it in the same way it does an array and give you each DOM element in the array. The array contains DOM elements and not jQuery objects.

Comment: ``someOb[3]` = third object in set` * = 4th object in set. JavaScript is 0-indexed, but english is not.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr)

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var Home = window.location.pathname;
    var path = $("#menu ul li a");

    path.attr('href', function (i, href) {
        console.log(this, href);
        return Home + href
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8Lr7B/)

Cause of the problem is `value` is a dom element reference which does not have the `.attr()` method, it is provided by jQuery object. So you need to use the jQuery wrapper for the `value`